# Error using clusterdump in mahout

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I am trying to run Kmeans with cosine similarity measure on mahout with hadoop to cluster text documents. I was able to cluster the documents, however, when I tried to view the output of the clusters with clusterdump I received the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to create parent directories of /mydocs/mytext-out-clust0

[image]

Could it be a permission problem? Please any clue on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this could be a permissions problem.

> Unable to create parent directories

indicates you don't have permissions to create parent directories.